# PyQt Button-Dictionary

Tags: python, button, dictionary, pyqt

I'm creating a dictionary of the buttons with:

```
self.edit = QtGui.QLabel('')
self.calcstring = ''
self.button = {}
for i in self.btn:
    self.button[i] = QtGui.QPushButton(i)
    if j == 2:
        self.grid.addWidget(self.edit, 0, 2)
    else:
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button[i], pos[j][0], pos[j][1])
    j += 1
```

Now all should get the Clicked-Function:

```
for i in self.btn:
    self.button[i].clicked.connect(self._action)
```

An at this Function, the Pressed-State should be readed, i did it so :

```
def _action(self):
if self.button['1'].clicked():
    sys.exit()
else:
    self.update(self.calcstring)
```

But the Error at Pressing a Button:

```
    if self.button['1'].clicked():
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `self.sender()` to get the widget that trigger the event, here is an example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
panel = QtGui.QWidget()
vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

def _action():
    print panel.sender().text()

for text in ["help", "update", "exit"]:
    button = QtGui.QPushButton(text)
    button.clicked.connect(_action)
    vbox.addWidget(button)

panel.setLayout(vbox)

panel.show()
app.exec_()
```

In your case:

```
if self.sender() is self.button['1']:
    ...
```